# Can I install 32-bit Ubuntu alongside OS X 10.7/10.8 in MacBook Pro?

Tags: 12.04, macosx, 12.10, macbook-pro

I have Samsung R430/P430 and MacBook Pro. The Samsung R430/P430 have Ubuntu and Windows 7 Ultimate. But in MacBook Pro is running Mac OS X 10.7/10.8. It has 100GB+ internal hard drive. Can i run 32-bit Ubuntu alongside Mac OS x?

Comment: There is an official documentation on [installing Ubuntu to all kinds apple PCs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation). And [specific pages for the MacBook Pro](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro).

Answer (score 1):

You are not stating if you are referring to a 13" or a 15" MBP

The answer is yes you can and its quite easy to get it working if its a 13" MBP

I would install [refit](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) in OSX prior to installing Ubuntu.

Since booting OSX grub from grub never worked for me and this worked out of the box.
I have never bothered to find out why it fails.

if you have a 15" MBP we would need more details to tell you if /how easy Ubuntu is to get working with it. Like exact version , and what graphic cards it has.

The 15" models are more bothersome because of the non stadard dual graphics setup.

Comment: I'm using 2010 13" MBP with Intel Core 2 Duo.

Comment: Install 64bit , not 32bit unless you have a very specific use case